# Open popup by imagebutton click on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have GridView(id: gv_test) with two columns:

> itemId
>
> ImageButton (id: ImageBTN)

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageBTN" Width="34px" Height="34px" ImageUrl="~/bla/bla.png" OnClick="ImageBTN_Click"  runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="PopUp"> </asp:ImageButton>
```

As you see, i tried somthing with OnRowCommand and with OnRowDataBound by using CommandName.. but without success, even not close.

The itemId get his value from sql table.

what i'm want to do - when the user click on the ImageButton - will open a popup with the link: test.aspx?id=itemId.

How i can to do that by c# (OnClick event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. I did something similar and this code was great help.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/gridview_popup.aspx